# php pathinfo() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, dir, pathinfo

I have a script that has the error-- **pathinfo() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in  C:\xampp\htdocs\sitename\index.php on line 4--**, how to fix a script is

```
    <?php          
    $dir = 'dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/';
    $phpfiles  = glob($dir ."*.php");
  line error --->   $pathinfo=  pathinfo($phpfiles, PATHINFO_FILENAME );


    foreach ($phpfiles as $phpfile){
         echo '<li><a href="'.$phpfile.'">'.$phpfile.'</a></li>'; 
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: I think the error message is kind of obvious

Comment: -1 for not even bothering to READ the error.

Comment: array != string, string required. use string, not array. error goes away then. see as well: http://php.net/pathinfo - double check input parameter types and return values.

Answer (score 1):

pathinfo returns an associative array, it does not allow an array as a parameter. See the docs: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php

Your glob will return an array with files.

path: The path to be parsed.
options: If present, specifies a specific element to be returned; one of PATHINFO_DIRNAME, PATHINFO_BASENAME, PATHINFO_EXTENSION or PATHINFO_FILENAME.

If options is not specified, returns all available elements.